# How to use jQuery toggle function multiple times

Tags: jquery

I have a page that's going to have 30 or so id's. I want to toggle them open/closed without having to write the following 28 more times. How would I do this?

First one:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#one").hide();
    $("#hide1").click(function(){
        $("#one").slideToggle(2000);
    });
});
```

Second one:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#two").hide();
    $("#hide2").click(function(){
        $("#two").slideToggle(2000);
    });
});
```

Would it make more sense to change the id's to something like #toggle1 and then use the starts-with selector ^= or something of the like?

Comment: use a class man a CLASS

Comment: post some part of  html

Comment: Post your html code.

Comment: Here's a codepen with HTML and CSS and JS. http://codepen.io/kiddigit/pen/EKGBoB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend this markup:

```
<!-- The element to click -->
<button id="one" class="button">Button</button>

<!-- The element to toggle -->
<div class="target-button" data-trigger="one">...</div>
```

jQuery

```
// Attach an event listener for .button class
$(document).on('click', '.button', function() {
   // Find the .target-button element
   // that has a 'data-trigger' attribute value equal to the clicked element's id
   $('.target-button[data-trigger="' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]').slideToggle(2000);
});
```

**NOTE**

- `this` returnes the clicked element (javascript DOM element).
- `$(this)` is just the jQuery object of `this`

Comment: This is good. I'm going to have to play with it so content starts hidden. It also seems to hide all the IDs. I appreciate your help. I'll work with it and see what I can do.

Comment: This is going to make me look like a noob, but what is (this) doing? Can you point me to documentation on that?